# How does one prove the following inequality is true?

Tags: inequality, fractions

I can prove that if $\frac{a_{i}}{b_{i}} \geq \frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}} $, it follows that $\frac{a_{i}}{b_{i}} \geq \frac{a_{i} + a_{j}}{b_{i} + b_{j}} $. However, I'd like to generalise this result by proving that if
$$ \frac{\sum_{i \in S} a_{i}}{\sum_{i \in S} b_{i}}  \geq \frac{\sum_{i \in T} a_{i}}{\sum_{i \in T} b_{i}},$$
it follows that
$$ \frac{\sum_{i \in S} a_{i}}{\sum_{i \in S} b_{i}}  \geq \frac{\sum_{i \in S \cup T} a_{i}}{\sum_{i \in S \cup T} b_{i}} $$ for any pair of sets $S$ and $T$.

Do you know how to prove the latter statement?

Comment: Using your previous result and induction might work

Comment: The first statement requires $b_j>0$. The second is easily proved considering $\sum_S a_i =A$ and so on directly from the first.

Comment: Induction.  Only concern is that the series converges.

Comment: By "any pair of sets," do you mean to include infinite sets?

Comment: @ConnorHarris nope, only finite ones.